# Node.js Mysql connection error inside modules

Tags: mysql, node.js

I created a Node.js web server. 
As my server.js file was getting too big I created modules. 
However I have a problem with my connection to the database.

```
// ========================= server.js ========================= 

const https = require('https');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use (express.static('public'))
app.use('/admin',require('./routeurs/admin'));
app.listen(300)
```

```
// ========================= admin.js ========================= 
var express = require('express');
var connection = require('./mysql');
var router = express.Router();

// This Works

connection.query("SELECT * FROM agent", (err, rows, result) => {
    console.log(rows)
})

router.get('/menu/users/getAccessFor/:user_id', (request, response) => {
   // This doesn't work
   console.log(connection)
   connection.query(SQL_query, (err, rows, fields) => {
            
  })
})

module.exports = router;
```

```
// ========================= mysql.js ========================= 
let mysql = require('mysql');
let fs    = require('fs');


var sql_security_logs = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('secret.json', 'utf8'))["sql_security_logs"];



var pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 10,
    host           : sql_security_logs["host"],
    user           : sql_security_logs["user"],
    password       : sql_security_logs["password"],
    database       : sql_security_logs["database"],
    port           : sql_security_logs["port"]
})


pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
    if (err) {
        if (err.code === 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST') {
            console.error('Database connection was closed.')
        }
        if (err.code === 'ER_CON_COUNT_ERROR') {
            console.error('Database has too many connections.')
        }
        if (err.code === 'ECONNREFUSED') {
            console.error('Database connection was refused.')
        }
    }    if (connection) connection.release()    
    return
})

module.exports = pool
```

On server initialization no problem, but as soon as I call the route I get the error "connection is not defined".

Comment: Why are you releasing the connection after acquiring?

Comment: Even i remove the connection.release() it doesn't work

Comment: Can you log err and connection on top to see the values? Are your credentials correct? And i query directly after createPool no need to getConnection or any other method.